# CSV email script efficiency

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, csv, email

I'm tasked with getting emails from a .csv file and using them to submit a form.  I am using the csv and mechanize Python libraries to achieve this.

```
import re
import mechanize
import csv

def auto_email(email):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open("URL")
    br.select_form(name="vote_session")
    br['email_add'] = '%s' % (email) #email address
    br.submit()

def csv_emails():
    ifile  = open('emails.csv', "rb")       
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    rownum = 1
    for row in reader:
        auto_email(row[0])
        print "%d - %s processed" %(rownum, row[0])
        rownum += 1
    print 'List processed.  You are done.'
    ifile.close()

print csv_emails()
```

The code works, but I am very much a beginner in Python.

I was wondering whether I have any inefficiencies that you can help me get rid of and optimize the script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to use

```
with open('emails.csv', "rb") as ifile
```

see here for details: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/
in this case you don't need to do `ifile.close` at the end

instead of incrementing rownum by yourself, you can use

```
for row, rownum in enumerate(reader):
```

I don't see the reason to do this

```
br['email_add'] = '%s' % (email) #email address
```

instead of

```
br['email_add'] = email
```

Comment: `email` comes from a row returned by `csv.reader` so it's always a string.

Comment: so in this case `br['email_add'] = email` is enough. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

`print csv_emails()` doesn't make sense. Since `csv_emails()` returns no value, there is nothing to print.